# set dropdown selected value with backbone

Tags: backbone.js

I want to set my dropdown menu from my js. Basically, i want to be able to set the updated drop down value from the js.

my.html

```
  <div class="dropDownList">
                    <select id="ddpFilter" >
                        <option value="1">Show 1</option>
                        <option value="2">Show 2</option>
                        <option value="3">Show 3</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
```

my.js

```
   events : {
     'change #ddpFilter' : 'Filter'
  },

  Filter : function(e){
      // Set Selected Value of the dropdown 
  }
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should start your function names with a lowercase letter ([as per Mr Crockford](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html)) and use more descriptive function names.

In order to set the value of a select list, use `option[value='x']` syntax. Assuming you'd like to set the second option:

```
events : {
  'change #ddpFilter' : 'filterDdpSelect'
},

filterDdpSelect: function(e){
  var selectValue = 2;
  $("#ddpFilter option[value='" + selectValue + "']").attr("selected", "selected");
}
```

Comment: Can we have any other alternative which doesn't manipulate the DOM without using jQuery??

Comment: i know it's and old question, but you can also use `$('#ddpFilter').val(selectValue)`