# Set default selection of Dropdown using Backbone

Tags: backbone.js

My question is quiet similar to [set-dropdown-selected-value-with-backbone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12940723/set-dropdown-selected-value-with-backbone), with minor difference that I don't want to manipulate the DOM thru jQuery.

For this what I have done is:-

Assuming my DropDown is of type `UserType`

```
var userType = backbone.Model.extend({
    idAttribute: "TypeId",
    defaults: {
        TypeId: null,
        TypeName: null,
        Selected: false
    }
});
```

Here, I have created an extra attribute as `Selected`, which I am using as below in my Handlebar template.

```
<select id="userType" name="UserTypeId" class="input-medium form-control">
    {{#each MasterUserType}}
    <option id="{{TypeId}}" selected="{{Selected}}">{{TypeName}}</option>
    {{/each}}
</select>
```

Okay, now when I get my Data thru api- say(example)

```
[
   {
      "TypeId":1,
      "TypeName":"Admin"
   },
   {
      "TypeId":2,
      "TypeName":"User"
   },
   {
      "TypeId":3,
      "TypeName":"Super Admin"
   }
]
```

Now, I manipulate my variable `MasterUserType` to become something like below:-

```
[
   {
      "TypeId":1,
      "TypeName":"Admin",
      "Selected":""
   },
   {
      "TypeId":2,
      "TypeName":"User",
      "Selected":"selected"
   },
   {
      "TypeId":3,
      "TypeName":"Super Admin",
      "Selected":""
   }
]
```

So my HTML which renders is :-

```
<div class="controls">
    <select id="userType" name="TypeId" class="input-medium form-control">

        <option id="" selected="">Admin</option>

        <option id="" selected="selected">User</option>
        <option id="" selected="">Super Admin</option>


    </select>
</div>
```

But still it reflects the first Item....

Can anyone tell me what is wrong? Or any other alternative?

Lastly, can we achieve this requirement from some other better way?

I have tried replacing "selected with true" but it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating your template as below:

```
<select id="userType" name="UserTypeId" class="input-medium form-control">
      {{#each MasterUserType}}
        {{#if Selected}}
            <option id="{{TypeId}}" selected="{{Selected}}">{{TypeName}}</option>
        {{else}}
            <option id="{{TypeId}}">{{TypeName}}</option>
        {{/if}}   
      {{/each}}
</select>
```

Comment: Can you help me with some alternative of that? As it works in this case, I have tried it. It throws error in console of IE7 saying `Missing attribute value on attribute 'selected'`...