# Showing selected item

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am trying to learn web development and I wrote a simple HTML code like

```
<div class="r" id="header-status">
     <a href="#" class="trigger" style="display: block; padding: 10px;">
        <span>
            <img src="{{STATIC_URL}}img/online.png">
        </span>
        &nbsp;ONLINE
        <span class="icon-down-dir">
        </span>
      </a>
      <ul class="dd-menu">
          <li>
             <a href="#"><span><img src="{{STATIC_URL}}img/away.png"></span>&nbsp;AWAY</a>
          </li>
          <li>
              <a href="#">
                 <span>
                    <img src="{{STATIC_URL}}img/offline.png">
                 </span>&nbsp;OFFLINE
              </a>
          </li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

Now I am trying to write a javascript code that I use Backbone to get what I select in the dropdown list. I mean when I clicked "away", I want to write "away" in the dropdown list.

Comment: Check out these links - [Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12940723/set-dropdown-selected-value-with-backbone) and [googleSearch](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=selected%20item%20in%20dropdownlist%20backbone)

Comment: What do you mean by *"dropdown list."* ..? assuming it's the `<ul>`, away is already an item in it. Then what do you mean *"when I clicked "away", I want to write "away" in the dropdown list"*..?!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to create a listener for click event. It can be done like this:

Your view:

```
// ...
View1.prototype.events = {
  "click .item": "menuClick"
};

View1.prototype.menuClick = function() {
  Backbone.trigger('menuItemSelected');
};
```

And a consumer on the click event (another view):

```
View2.prototype.initialize = function() {
  this.listenTo(Backbone, 'menuItemSelected', this.selectMenuItem);
};


View2.prototype.selectMenuItem = function() {
  console.log('item selected');
}
```